# Custom properties defined in base form lose their state in inherited form upon rebuild

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, properties, designer

I am having trouble with properties of a base form not maintaining state in an inherited form.

**Environment:**

- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Service Pack 1: Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
- .Net Framework: Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel
- Windows 7 Ultimate

Below, is the source code and steps to reproduce:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class BaseForm : Form
    {
        [DefaultValueAttribute(true)]
        public bool ControlVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return this.checkBox1.Visible;
            }
            set
            {
                this.checkBox1.Visible = value;
            }
        }

        [DefaultValueAttribute(false)]
        public bool ControlChecked
        {
            get
            {
                return this.checkBox1.Checked;
            }
            set
            {
                this.checkBox1.Checked = value;
            }
        }

        public BaseForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above the default properties match up with the [DefaultValueAttribute], i.e. in InitializeComponent() checkBox1.Visible is set to true and checkBox1.Checked is false. These are the default settings for the control when dropped onto the form.

I then created the following inherited form:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : BaseForm
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**Issue and steps to reproduce:**

1. When I open Form1 in the designer the properties are the in following state.

   State: ControlChecked = False - ControlVisible = **True** (bold)

   *ControlVisible* is set to *True* as expected, however it is bold. The [DefaultValueAttribute] is set to *true* in the base form, so I would have expected this property to not be in bold.
2. I now change *ControlVisible* to *False* in the designer. The bold turns off.

   State: ControlChecked = False - ControlVisible = False
3. I now rebuild the project and the code in Form1 gets regenerated. The *ControlVisible* property reverts back to *True* in bold.

   State: ControlChecked = False - ControlVisible = **True** (bold)
4. I now change *ControlChecked* from *False* to *True* and it becomes bold as expected.

   State: ControlChecked = **True** (bold) - ControlVisible = **True** (bold)
5. I rebuild the project and no change.

   State: ControlChecked = **True** (bold) - ControlVisible = **True** (bold)
6. I now change the property of *ControlVisible* from *True* to *False* and rebuild the project again. *ControlVisible* flipped back to *True* in bold.

   State: ControlChecked = **True** (bold) - ControlVisible = **True** (bold)

*ControlChecked* appears to be working as expected. *ControlVisible* keeps flipping back to *True* when it is set to false and the bold is reversed. Seems to me that somehow the [DefaultAttributeValue] of *true* in the base form is not recognized.

**Update:**
Revised to fix a bug and more exactly isolate the issue.

**Update:**
If I set checkBox1.Visible = false in the constructor of BaseForm, then everything works as expected. So, bottom line it appears that the trouble is getting the DefaultValueAttribute of *true* to be recognized on the custom property in the inherited form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your `checkBox1` private in the base class? If it's not then it should be, because the designer will serialize both setters (one for checkBox1.Visible and the other for ControlVisible), and only the order of serialization will determine the final state, which is bad.

Also, look at the autogenerated InitializeControls method in the Form1.designer.cs file, does it explicitly set the custom properties to default values?

Finally, try using [ShouldSerialze and Reset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e.aspx) and see if you get different behavior.

**Edit**

I've recreated the problem locally and attached one VS instance to debug another. The first time the property `ControlVisible` was evaluated by VS it returned `false` because `checkBox1.Visible` (the getter source) was `false`. When the actual checkbox control was created and shown, and the Properties window was scrolled to display `ControlVisible` it's value was evaluated again and it returned *true* which is the default value, however it seems that VS internally already tagged that propery as modified, since it's *initial* value was different than the default. This may be a bug in VS.

I've created a simple demonstration of the effect:

```
    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _testValue = false;
    }

    private bool _testValue;

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool TestProperty
    {
        get { return _testValue; }
        set { _testValue = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {            
        _testValue = true;
        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
    }
}
```

When inheriting the above `BaseForm` the `TestPropery` behaves exactly like the `ControlVisible` in your example, so I think it's a bug in VS.

The solution to your problem is to use a simple bool backing field as a helper, because checkBox1.Visible is unreliable:

```
    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        checkBox1.Visible = _controlVisible = true;
    }

    private bool _controlVisible;

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool ControlVisible
    {
        get { return _controlVisible; }
        set { _controlVisible = checkBox1.Visible = value; }
    }
```

Comment: checkBox1 is private in base class. Form1.designer.cs explicitly sets ControlVisible when it is set to "true", which is reversed. This is the default property and it does not set it when it is "false". I tried out ShouldSerialize and Reset and this made no difference. The inherited form has the default value reversed on the custom property ControlVisible. It is somehow not recognizing the DefaultAttribute setting in base class and also appeared to ignore the ShouldSerialize/Reset.

Comment: Strange, I made a local demo and it works like you described. When a private bool field is the source for ControlVisible it works as expected, but when the source is checkBox1.Visible it doesn't work.

Comment: When I set ControlVisible = false and change [DefaultAttribute(false)] on the property. Then inherited form also works as expected. Appears to boil down to [DefaultAttribute(true)] not taking.

Comment: I ran your test on a private bool field as the source and it works for me too as expected. While awkward, this leads to solution of mirroring the underlying control's visible state (same occurs with Panel control) in a private bool field. Would be nice to get this resolved without having to mirror the control's visible state.

Answer (score 4):

Your ControlVisible property always gets set to false:

```
    [DefaultValueAttribute(true)]
    public bool ControlVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return this.checkBox1.Visible;
        }
        set
        {
            this.checkBox1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Your set method should be:

```
    this.checkBox1.Visible = value;
```

Comment: Very sharp indeed! Wow, that was embarrassing. I fixed the code and that resolved a couple of anomalies - one issue remains.