# C# Creating a Base Form with Custom Properties

Tags: c#, winforms, radix, inheritance

I am having a small issue where the defined custom property value is not sticking in the inherited form.

The code in my base form is:

```
namespace ContractManagement.Forms
{
    public partial class BaseForm : Form
    {
        public BaseForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Boolean DialogForm
        {
            get
            {
                return TitleLabel.Visible;
            }
            set
            {
                TitleLabel.Visible = value;
                CommandPanel.Visible = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
            TitleLabel.Text = Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the form that inherits this I have:

```
namespace ContractManagement.Forms
{
    public partial class MainForm : Forms.BaseForm
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, despite what I set in MainForm for DialogForm, on runtime it reverts back to True.

There is another post on this site which mentions this, but I don't get what it explains.

I also want to create a property which allows me to hide the ControlBox, so how do I add this in?

Comment: Take a look at some of this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872849/custom-properties-defined-in-base-form-lose-their-state-in-inherited-form-upon-r

Comment: @DJKRAZE - That is the other post I was referring to, but I don't understand what is wrong with just doing the above.  What do I need to do different with my code compared to what is in the answer in the other post because I have two things I am trying to set.

Comment: For starters what properties and or values are you trying to store and or get access to.. meaning in the link after the Initialize notice how the link has Initialize then _some control name..for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have done it now:

```
namespace ContractManagement.Forms
    {
        public partial class BaseForm : Form
        {
            private Boolean DialogStyle;
            private Boolean NoControlButtons;

            public BaseForm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                TitleLabel.Visible = DialogStyle = true;
                ControlBox = NoControlButtons = true;
            }

            public Boolean DialogForm
            {
                get
                {
                    return DialogStyle;
                }
                set
                {
                    DialogStyle = TitleLabel.Visible = value;
                    DialogStyle = CommandPanel.Visible = value;
                }
            }

            public Boolean ControlButtons
            {
                get
                {
                    return NoControlButtons;
                }
                set
                {
                    NoControlButtons = ControlBox = value;
                }
            }

            protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnTextChanged(e);
                TitleLabel.Text = Text;
            }
        }
    }
```