# how to add custom property to windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-properties

I would like to add custom property to windows form not to control so when I click form property in designer view I could see this property and change it

Comment: One way to do it would be to make a custom control inherting from `Form` and add your property.

Comment: You can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467295/c-sharp-creating-a-base-form-with-custom-properties